# Sound lost after running CCleaner

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, windows-10, ccleaner

After running CCleaner, I've a very strangle problem with my audio device :

- If I start the computer with the headphone's jack plugged in, I'll only have sound with the head phone, the laptop's speaker won't function and vice versa (start the computer without the headphone's jack plugged in)
- Like I said above, I still have sound but only on Chrome!!! not on Firefox, not on Windows media player ...
- I tried uninstall the audio's driver and re-install it but the problem remained.
- When I tried to open some music file using foobar, I'll get the error : Unrecoverable playback error: Unknown error code (0x88890008)
- System sounds (eg: beep sound...) still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the audio driver is corrupt. That means it is likely that uninstall did not succeed. Although a simple uninstall can often leave behind low level settings. Try removing the device following the instructions in this Microsoft document.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I did not follow this instruction but I tried to uninstall the driver & have the option "Delete the driver setup file .. " ticked, then I let windows do the automatic installation, and everything worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > System Restore.
Choose "Restore my computer to an earlier time."
Then, choose a bold date on the calendar a couple of days before you started getting the problem. Proceed with the restore, and see if it solves your problem.
(**CAUTION:** Will uninstall programs installed after that date, but will not touch your personal files.)

Comment: unfortunately the system restore function was disabled :(